# Visual Studio Code change language mode depending on project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

how can i change language mode in visual studio code depending on project i have opened? For example in one project i want to set language mode to standard javascript file for  .js files. In another project i want to set language mode to react for .js files.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In each project, open the `workspace settings` (using the command `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings`) and enter settings like:

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascript"
  },
```

or

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  },
```

respectively.